# How to get rid of ridiculously high loss when data is already normalized?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, tf.keras

I have 500 sample of housing data which I have converted all to numbers. It has  12 columns which are used to predict 1 price.

However, when I try to run the model, its loss is massive(14 digit loss). I have normalize the data but this had no effect. This is causing the programs predictions to be very off, x100 off. what can i do to fix this. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler

data = pd.read_csv('Housing.csv')
valdata = pd.read_csv('val.csv')

mapping1 = {'yes': 1, 'no': 0}
mapping2 = {'furnished': 2, 'semi-furnished': 1, "unfurnished": 0}


cols_to_convert = ['mainroad', 'guestroom', "basement", "hotwaterheating", "airconditioning", "prefarea"]
for col in cols_to_convert:
    data[col] = data[col].map(mapping1)
    valdata[col] = valdata[col].map(mapping1)

data["furnishingstatus"] = data["furnishingstatus"].map(mapping2)
valdata["furnishingstatus"] = valdata["furnishingstatus"].map(mapping2)



x_train = np.array(data.drop("price", axis=1))
y_train = np.array(data["price"])


scaler = MinMaxScaler()
x_train = scaler.fit_transform(x_train)

scaler = StandardScaler()
x_train = scaler.fit_transform(x_train)

input_shape = x_train[0].shape

inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)

# Define  layers
dense1 = Dense(8, activation='relu')(inputs)
dense2 = Dense(1, activation='linear')(dense1)

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=dense2)

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=100, validation_split=0.2)

x_new = np.array([[7420, 4, 2, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2]])
y_new = model.predict(x_new)
print(y_new)
```

And hers is roughly what the csv file looks like before mapping the strings to numbers.
[Image of csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ne0P6.png)

Comment: Your x_new does not look like normalized data.

Comment: And you did not normalize the labels, which is the source of the problem.

Comment: when I normalize the new data, it becomes even less accurate. What do you mean by normalize the labels?

Comment: How do you normalize the new data, do you transform with the fitted scaler or do you fit_transform a new scaler?

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22776/is-it-valuable-to-normalize-rescale-labels-in-neural-network-regression

Comment: I normalize the data with scaler = MinMaxScaler()
x_train = scaler.fit_transform(x_train)

scaler = StandardScaler()
x_train = scaler.fit_transform(x_train)

Comment: ill see if I can dind how to normalize the labels

Answer (score 0):

You can try to improve your model by increasing the number of hidden layers (say from 1 to 2) or/and increasing the number of units in hidden Dense layers (say to 256 and 64).

But actually you might get better results when using other ML algorithms, like Random Forests or XGBoost instead of DNN. Please check the following article, which shows that Random Forests outperform DNN for tabular data like you have:
https://www.kdnuggets.com/2019/06/random-forest-vs-neural-network.html

Comment: Adding a second layer makes it even less accurate as it retuns values less than 1 but the value should be around a million, as for the random forest generator I don't know how to make that work as of now so id rather not use it.

Comment: Do you transform the x_new in the same way as x_train before passing it as input to the model?

Comment: yes, its not that the model is inaccurate the model is literally incorrect, its answers are way off. logically, the code is right no?

Comment: Yes, the code looks ok. You might also try other loss functions, like Huber loss to see if it works better than MSE.

Comment: thank you for the help, I think the data somehow just has absolutely no correlation somehow. I really doubt it but I changed the data to a churn dataset and the same model has 95% accuracy for testing and 80% for validation